# C++Builder XE Raw SSL socket

Tags: c++, c++builder, c++builder-xe7

I need to connect to a server with SSL in C++Builder XE7. I can find stuff for HTTPS and SMTP but nothing for custom connections. In BCB5 it was a lot easier, I would do it with custom code but now with Android and iOS, things need to be done a little differently as we now need to support these products too.

I've looked at TIdSocketSSL but with the very few examples I could find, it seems to need an owner which ultimate comes from SMTP or HTTPS.

Answer (score 2):

C++Builder ships with Indy, which has a `TIdTCPClient` component that you can use for implementing custom protocols.  There are plenty of examples on Embarcadero's forum, Indy's forum, StackOverflow, and various blogs demonstrating how to send/receive custom data with Indy.

For SSL/TLS, simply assign a `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` component to the `TIdTCPClient::IOHandler` property before calling `Connect()`, and configure its properties as needed (certificates, SSL/TLS version(s), etc). When you want to perform the SSL handshake, set the `TIdSSLIOHandlerOpenSSL::PassThrough` property to false.  You can set it before calling `Connect()` so the handshake is immediate before any data is exchanged (aka *implicit SSL/TLS*), or you can set it after exchanging unencrypted data first (aka *explicit SSL/TLS*), depending on your protocol needs.